# Android: Trying to create a spinner with items based on another spinner's item selected

Tags: java, android

I have a spinner with items mg, g, micrograms, kg. If I select mg, I want the 2nd spinner updated with mg and g items only. But when the use the if logic I get " The method createFromResource(Context, int, int) in the type ArrayAdapter is not applicable for the argume" error.

public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener{

```
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id){
    String str = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

    final TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);

    if (str.equals("mg")){
        Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.units, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
        //result.setText("testing");
    }
    else {
        result.setText("micrograms");
    }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent){}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is on this line:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.units, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

The first argument here takes a Context. Because you're calling it from a listener, which is its own class, `this` refers to the listener, not to your activity. You need to pass a reference to your activity in through the constructor of your listener class, and replace `this` with a reference to that activity context.

Comment: yup that was it. Thank you.

Comment: Since you're new here, a heads up - If my answer (or anyone else's) was helpful to you, please consider accepting it (by clicking the checkmark beside it). Doing so will give you +2 reputation points, and increase the likelihood that folks will help you out in the future :)